# Calling Firebase Function from Unity throws error

Tags: javascript, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am having problems with my Unity3D calling Firebase Functions function. My code is actually copied from https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable.

My function code is following: (just copied this file actually)
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/a579893cfa33121952aeed9069c1554ed4e65b7e/functions/functions/index.js#L44-L50

and in Unity I have this:

```
//Create the arguments to the callable function.
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data["text"] = "message";
        data["push"] = true;

        //Call the function and extract the operation from the result.
        var function = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable("addMessage");
        function.CallAsync(data).ContinueWith((task) => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                foreach (var inner in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (inner is FunctionsException)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(inner.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Finished: " + task.Result.Data);
            }
        });
```

But I am getting this result:
Response is not valid JSON object.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: At what line are you getting the error?

Answer (score -2):

I was still working on that problem and suddenly it worked. I dont know why to be honest, because the could looks exactely the same and I did not change anything on that.